# VS2013 C# projects in VS2015: Will they use the Roslyn compiler?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

Not entirely certain that this is even a valid question, however if I use VS2015 to open a solution that was originally created and maintained with VS2013, will it be compiled using the Roslyn compiler platform whenever built (within VS2015)?

The solution consists of WPF applications, Console applications, Web Applications, Windows Service applications and of course class libraries - so a good all round selection of options.

If this is not the case, how should I enable the Roslyn compiler for these projects?

Thanks.

Comment: The project's origin doesn't matter, it's the language version that's important. C# 6 will definitely use Roslyn. I think C# 5 won't but I'm not certain - I switched to 6 immediatelly after migrating

Comment: How do you change from C#5 to C#6; is this not implied by the change of Visual Studio?

Comment: Project Properties > Build > Advanced > Language Version. The default is 6. As I said, I switched immediatelly after migrating. I don't remember what the initial setting was. Just try it, eg use a C# 6 feature like an interpolated string

Comment: VS 2015 by default uses Roslyn compiler. it is backward compatible so you don't see any difference. If you use any C# 6.0 features then you will get to know the difference.

Comment: Ok, so given that I am using VS2015, and the Language Version for the project is set to "default", then I can use C#6 features and this will be compiled using Roslyn. I just need to be aware that it will then no longer be backward compatible with VS2013. Is this correct?

Comment: If you want your project to remain compatible with VS2013, just set the language version to C# 5.

Answer (score 7):

If you open in VS2015, it will always use the Roslyn compiler to compile, regardless of the language version switch.

Using the `/langversion` switch simply tells the Roslyn compiler not to allow new features - it doesn't cause an older compiler to be used.